# Module does not evaluate the same way as without

Tags: scoping

I have a module as follows:

```
mytangent[f_, x0_] := 
 Module[{},
  i[x_] = D[f[x], x];
  d = f[x0];
  rise = Simplify[i[x0]];
  Print["y = ", rise, "*x", " + ", d];
  ]
```

and "normal" lines like this:

```
i[x_] = D[f[x], x]
d = f[x0]
rise = Simplify[i[x0]]
Print["y = ", rise, "x", " + ", d]
```

If i insert a function `f[x_] = x^2 + x - 2` with `x0 = 3`
I get

`y = (-2+x+x^2)´[3]*x+ (-2+x+x^2)[3]`

from the module and the correct answer from the second couple lines as:

`y = 7x + 10`

How do I make my module give me the same result?

Comment: How did you insert your function into `mytangent`?

Comment: With `mytangent[x^2 + x - 2, 3]`

Comment: You need to use `mytangent[Function[x, x^2 + x - 2], 3]` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is working :) Never expected i had to specify that it is a function... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you may want to read [#18393](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393).